# What's the right way to make a stack (or other dynamically resizable vector-like thing) in Rust?

Tags: vector, stack, dynamic-arrays, rust

Google turns up many links on [old methods](http://osdir.com/ml/rust-mozilla-developemnt/2012-06/msg00076.html) that [have now been removed from the language](https://github.com/mozilla/rust/pull/5279), but I can't find a reference on what to do for Rust 0.6.

I've just implemented a linked list, which I could easily repurpose into a stack, but I'd rather use some well-tested, robust, existing data structure from the standard library.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would try, in order :

- a [deque](http://static.rust-lang.org/doc/0.6/std/deque.html)
- a [list](http://static.rust-lang.org/doc/0.6/std/list.html) or a [dlist](http://static.rust-lang.org/doc/std/dlist.html)
- a [vec](http://static.rust-lang.org/doc/0.6/core/vec.html)
- a [mutable owned vector](http://static.rust-lang.org/doc/0.6/tutorial.html#vectors-and-strings)

You can [learn more about the containers on the wiki](https://github.com/mozilla/rust/wiki/Containers).